# Android onBackPress issue activity switching

Tags: android

i have four activities in application

A,B,C,D

and the flow of the activities are A->B->C->D

on back press i want to move from D->C->B only i dont want to go activity A how can i restrict the application to move to A from B

Comment: you can finish activity a finish(); when you are calling startActivity(b);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put noHistory="true" on your Activity in the AndroidManifest.xml, you won't go back to Activity A.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example">
    <application ...>

        <activity 
            android:name=".activity.ActivityA"
            android:noHistory="true"/>

        ...

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you start your activity B from activity A, call finish() on activity A. E.g.:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
   startActivity(intent);
   A.this.finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

when you are going to activity `B` from `A` just call `finish()` in activity `A`.Let that you are moving from activity `A` to activity `B` on some button click,then in `onClick()` method,you have to do something like this

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    Intent i=new Intent(A.this,B.class);
    startActivity(i);
    A.this.finish();

}
```